# Help needed to understand the proof of "If $[G:H]=2$, the $H$ is normal in $G$".

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

The statement "If $[G:H]=2$, the $H$ is normal in $G$", has the following proof:

$G= N \cup g N = N \cup Ng $ for any $g\in G \setminus  N$.

Therefore $Ng=gN$.

I don't understand why $G= N \cup g N = N \cup Ng $ is the case.

Comment: Because the equivalence classes of an equivalence relation form a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of a set. The $gN$-s are the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff y^{-1}x\in N$ and the $Ng$-s are the ones of $x\simeq y\iff xy^{-1}\in N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the index is $2$, there are two cosets (they can be identified with $1$ and $g$, picking any $g$ not in $N$).

Since $G$ is the disjoint union of its left cosets, you have that $G=N \cup gN$, and since $G$ is also the disjoint union of its right cosets, $G= N \cup Ng$.

Ps: I am guessing that $H=N$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Since index of $H$ is $2$ in $G$, that means there are only two **distinct** left(and right) cosets of $H$ in $G$. i.e. $H$ and $aH$ for all $a \notin G-H$ (and $H$ and $Ha$ for all $a \notin G-H$ (for right cosets)).

As you know these cosets partition the group $G$, hence $G=H \cup aH$ and $G=H \cup Ha$.